# How to make inverted bar chart on the x-axis in c3.js

Tags: javascript, charts, bar-chart, c3.js

I was able to achieve this with c3.js

[image]

this is my c3.js code.

```
            var chart = c3
        .generate({
            bindto : "#topUses",
            size : {
                height : 180,
                width : 400
            },
            bar : {
                width : 14
            },
            padding : {
                left : 100,
                top : 50
            },
            color : {
                pattern : [ '#ff1919', '#ff1919', '#ff1919', '#ff1919',
                        '#ff1919' ]
            },
            data : {
                x : 'x',
                columns : [
                        [ 'x', 'Google', 'Yahoo', 'Facebook',
                                'Capital One', 'Express' ],
                        [ 'value', 160, 310, 232, 405, 200 ] ],

                type : 'bar',

                color : function(inColor, data) {
                    var colors = [ '#ff1919', '#ff1919', '#ff1919',
                            '#ff1919', '#ff1919' ];
                    if (data.index !== undefined) {
                        return colors[data.index];
                    }

                    return inColor;
                }
            },
            axis : {
                rotated : true,
                x : {
                    type : 'category',
                    show : false,
                },
                y : {
                    show : false
                }
            },
            tooltip : {
                grouped : false
            },
            legend : {
                show : false
            }
        });
```

I want to achieve this, any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use css transform to miror the group containing bars and play with transform-origin to keep it in place in the svg :

```js
      var chart = c3
        .generate({
            bindto : "#topUses",
            size : {
                height : 180,
                width : 400
            },
            bar : {
                width : 14
            },
            padding : {
                left : 100,
                top : 50
            },
            color : {
                pattern : [ '#ff1919', '#ff1919', '#ff1919', '#ff1919',
                        '#ff1919' ]
            },
            data : {
                x : 'x',
                columns : [
                        [ 'x', 'Google', 'Yahoo', 'Facebook',
                                'Capital One', 'Express' ],
                        [ 'value', 160, 310, 232, 405, 200 ] ],

                type : 'bar',

                color : function(inColor, data) {
                    var colors = [ '#ff1919', '#ff1919', '#ff1919',
                            '#ff1919', '#ff1919' ];
                    if (data.index !== undefined) {
                        return colors[data.index];
                    }

                    return inColor;
                }
            },
            axis : {
                rotated : true,
                x : {
                    type : 'category',
                    show : false,
                },
                y : {
                    show : false
                }
            },
            tooltip : {
                grouped : false
            },
            legend : {
                show : false
            }
        });
```

```css
.c3-chart{
transform-origin: 120px 0px;
transform:scale(-1,1);
}
```

```html
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.9/c3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.3/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="topUses"></div>
```

another tricky way is to invert the value [ 'value', -160, -310, -232, -405, -200 ] , then you have to find something to remove "-" in the legends